# Best Approach to Scrape Paginated Results using import.io

Tags: pagination, web-scraping, import.io

There are several websites within the cruise industry that I would like to scrape.
Examples:
http://www.silversea.com/cruise/cruise-results/?page_num=1
http://www.seabourn.com/find-luxury-cruise-vacation/FindCruises.action?cfVer=2&destCode=&durationCode=&dateCode=&shipCodeSearch=&portCode=

In some scenarios, like the first one shown, the results page follows a patten - ?page_num=1...17. However the number of results will vary over time.

In the second scenario, the URL does not change with pagination.

At the end of the day, what I'd like to do is to get the results for each website into a single file.

Q1: Is there any alternative to setting 17 scrapers for scenario 1 and then actively watching as results grow/shrink over time?

Q2: I'm completely stumped about how to scrape content from second scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Q1- The free tool from (import.io) does not have the ability to actively watch the data change over time. What you could do is have the data Bulk Extracted by the Extractor (with 17 pages this would be really fast) and added to a database. After each entry to the database, the entries could be de-duped or marked as unique. You could do this manually in Excel or programmatically.

Their Enterprise (data as a service) could do this for you.

Q2- If there is not a unique URL for each page, the only tool that will paginate the pages for you is the Connector.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to build an extractor to get the pagination. The result of this extractor will be a list of links, each link corresponding to a page.

This way, every time you run your application and the number of pages changes, you will always get all the pages.

After that, make a call for each page to get the data you want.

Extractor 1: Get pages -- Input: The first URL

Extractor 2: Get items (data) -- Input: The result from Extractor 1